# How to modify the query in taxonomy-custom.php to sort term archives by a custom meta field?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I am trying to create theme pages for custom taxonomy terms in which the archives are ordered by a custom meta field.

I can do this with a new wp_query as follows:

```
        <?php $directory_archive_query = new WP_Query( 
            array( 
                'post_type' => 'directory',
                'posts_per_page' => 200,
                'meta_key' => 'surname',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>    

            <?php while($directory_archive_query->have_posts()) : $directory_archive_query->the_post(); ?>
```

However, I need this to work on the taxonomy-custom.php page so that each individual taxonomy term's archive page is listed according to the custom meat field (called 'surname'). If I use the wp_query, then of course that doesn't work, because it no longer shows results for each specific term.

I have also tried to do this using pre_get_posts, but can't make that work either. What I am expecting to happen is that all posts listed on the term archive page will be listed in ascending order by the surname meta key. That is not happening. Instead, they are just listing in the same order as if there were no pre_get_posts there. The code I have used is as follows:

```
<?php 

    function customize_customtaxonomy_archive_display ( $query ) {
        if (($query->is_main_query()) && (is_tax('services')))

        $query->set( 'post_type', 'directory' );                 
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '200' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'surname' );           
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }

     add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'customize_customtaxonomy_archive_display' );

?>
```

Really hoping that someone can help.

Thanks for your time.

Andrew.

Comment: Creating custom, secondary queries to replace the *main* query is the wrong approach. You [need to use `pre_get_posts`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) to modify the main query instead.

Comment: Thanks @ChipBennett. I have tried doing that too, but I can't get it to work. Is there any way you can show me how the code would work in this example please?

Comment: Can you **edit your question** to include your attempt to use `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: Sure, just give me a moment...

Comment: Okay I have edited the question to show my attempt

Comment: Can you clarify "*but I can't make that work either*"? What are you *expecting* to happen that doesn't happen, or what happens *unexpectedly*? Also: why are you forcing the `post_type`? That should be handled automatically if the taxonomy is registered for the post type.

Comment: Okay, have removed the post type and that makes no difference. What I am expecting to happen is that all posts listed on the term archive page will be listed according in ascending order by the surname meta key.

That is not happening. Instead, they are just listing in the same order as if there were no pre_get_posts there.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add clarifying details, so they don't get lost in the comments.

Comment: Okay, I have edited that information into the question too.

Comment: Thanks! Do the other `$query->set()` values work, e.g. `posts_per_page`? And just to double-check: when testing `pre_get_posts`, you're outputting the **Main Query Loop** in `taxonomy-services.php`, right?

Comment: Okay, actually no, none of the values work. Even the posts_per_page is not working. What does that even mean?

I am using the standard Wordpress loop in that file:

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

I have also just noticed that, with this pre_get_posts code in place, my sidebar (which comes after the code) is missing from the page.

Comment: That means you have a syntax error in your `pre_get_posts` callback. For one thing: you're missing your curly braces on your conditional.

Comment: Okay, have added the curly braces. The sidebar is back but still no joy with the query.

Comment: Does `posts_per_page` work? Or do none of the parameters work?

Comment: None of them are working. I have tried reducing posts_per_page to just two, for testing it, and it is being ignored.

Comment: That means your conditional isn't working. Try changing `is_tax( 'services' )` to `$query->is_tax( 'services' )`.

Comment: How are you testing that the parameters are being ignored? Assuming your tax condition matches your code works? ___Where___ is the `pre_get_posts` filter? What file? Are you actually using `taxonomy-custom.php` as written or is it `taxonomy-<tax-name>.php`?

Comment: Hi @ChipBennett - I tried substituting that, and still the same issue (the query effectively being ignored).

Comment: To @s_ha_dum yes the file is named taxonomy-services.php

Comment: And my other questions?

Comment: @s_ha_dum The pre_get_posts filter is immediately before the loop begins in taxonomy-services.php

Comment: Please keep comments threads short, there is chat for more extensive discussions.

Comment: @Rarst okay - but how am I supposed to have my question resolved otherwise?

Comment: By discussing it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) if extensive discussion is needed?.. :)

Comment: Thankfully it's been resolved, as I am unable to aprticipate in chat (reputation points)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The pre_get_posts filter is immediately before the loop begins in
>   `taxonomy-services.php`

That is too late. The main query runs long before your template loads. Move your `pre_get_posts` filter to your theme's `functions.php`, or a plugin or MU-Plugin file, and you should see the difference.

Comment: Is this for sure? I have never seen any advice on this anywhere before. Surely I only need it to work on this template file?

Comment: Man, you are a saviour! I have moved it to functions.php and it's now working beautifully! Thanks so much for your time :)

Comment: Yes, this is for sure. You have to add the hook before the query runs and the main query runs before the template loads-- it is what _determines_ what template to load. You can add a `pre_get_posts` action just before new `WP_Query` objects that you create.

Comment: +1. Second day in a row: I set 'em up, and @s_ha_dum knocks 'em down! Teamwork. :)

Comment: Awesome, thank so much guys. I couldn't see it but had no idea of the need to put it there. Genius team yous make in that case ;)